# Return Month Date Data when Week Date is entered

Tags: date, ms-access, datepart

I have a table setup with a heap of figures given in a monthly sense.  I am setting up a query to break it down into weekly figures.  How do I make the query return the correct data?

This is how I want the data to come out (In Excel):

[image]

This is a cross post from [access-programmers.co.uk](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=1512762#post1512762).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a From, you can do it like this:

```
FIELD: YourDateField
CRITERIA: Between FORMS![YourFormName]!cboStartDate and Forms![YourFormName]!cboEndDate
```

If you want to use VBA, you can do it like this.

```
Dim strWhere As String
Dim conJetDate ="\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"
If IsNull(Me.cboStartDate) Or IsNull(Me.cboEndDate) Then
MsgBox "Both dates needed"
Else
strWhere = "[MyDate] Between " & _
Format(Me.cboStartDate, conJetDate) & " And " & _
Format(Me.cboEndDate, conJetDate)
Me.Filter = strWhere
Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```